# arr1=range("A", "z"); $arr2= range(0,9);

Tags: php

```
$arr1 = range("A", "z");
$arr2 = range(0,9);
```

Как сделать, чтобы указав N число из этих массивов, печатать случайным образом и цифры и буквы?

Comment: т.е. вы хотите объединённый range? вам к array_merge

Comment: array_merge сливает один за другим а мне нужно rand()

Comment: Второй вариант в ответе ниже вам чем не подходит?

Comment: array['a',1,'A',8,'L'] и такдале

Comment: https://3v4l.org/JBIsu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

суть не понятна, но смею предположить что так

```
$common = array();
$common[] = range('A', 'z');
$common[] = range(0, 9);

$length = 5;
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i++; $i<$length) {
  shuffle($common[0]);
  shuffle($common[1]);
  $result[] = common[rand(0, 1)][0]
}
```

или

```
$length = 6;
$literals = range('A', 'z');
$numbers = range(0, 9);
$common = array_merge($literals, $numbers);
shuffle($common);
$result = implode($common);
$result = substr($result, 0, $length);
```

Answer (score 0):

`range('A', 'z');` содержит много лишних символов между `Z` и `a`.
Вы можете использовать 3 различных range для вашей задачи:

```
$alphabet = array_merge(
  range('a', 'z'),  // строчные
  range('A', 'Z'),  // прописные
  range(0, 9)       // числа
);
shuffle($alphabet);   // перемешиваем
$result = array_slice($alphabet, 0, 10); // выбираем первые 10
echo json_encode($result); // выводим результат (в json)
// ["N","O","c","P","r","W","f",7,"V","A"]
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/ES8ob)